# jquery animate problem

Tags: jquery

I am creating a "simple" animated menu using .animate() to enlarge the menu item the user hovers over. This works almost right but it does some odd things if they user moves the cursor quickly. Plus the elements don't always animate simultaneously.

Easiest way to show it is with the following link.

http://jsfiddle.net/322c5/2/

or

```
<head>
<script src="jquery-ui/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#test1").hover( function () {
    $(this).animate( { width:"599px",left:"0px", height:"168px" }, 100 )
  },
  function () {
    $(this).animate( { width:"246px",left:"9px", height:"84px" }, 100 )
  }
);

$("#test2").hover( function () {
    $(this).animate( { width:"599px",left:"0px", height:"168px", top:"-21px" }, 100 )
    $(".test").animate( { top:"-21px" }, 100 )
  },
  function () {
    $(this).animate( { width:"246px",left:"9px", height:"84px", top:"0px" }, 100 )
    $(".test").animate( { top:"0px" }, 100 )
  }
);

$("#test3").hover( function () {
    $(this).animate( { width:"599px",left:"0px", height:"168px", top:"-63px" }, 100 )
    $(".test").animate( { top:"-63px" }, 100 )
  },
  function () {
    $(this).animate( { width:"246px",left:"9px", height:"84px", top:"0px" }, 100 )
    $(".test").animate( { top:"0px" }, 100 )
  }
);

$("#test4").hover( function () {
    $(this).animate( { width:"599px",left:"0px", height:"168px", top:"-84px" }, 100 )
    $(".test").animate( { top:"-84px" }, 100 )
  },
  function () {
    $(this).animate( { width:"246px",left:"9px", height:"84px", top:"0px" }, 100 )
    $(".test").animate( { top:"0px" }, 100 ) 
  }
);



});

</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .container {
        width:599px; background-color:#000;padding:0px;  height:336px; overflow-y:hidden;
    }

    .test {
        width:246px; background-color:#039; left:9px; top:0px; position:relative; height:84px;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div id="test1" class="test">
      test
      </div>
        <div id="test2" class="test">
            test
        </div>
        <div id="test3" class="test">
            test
        </div>
        <div id="test4" class="test">
            test
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Linking to live examples is great, but **always** also include the relevant code in your actual question. External links can disappear, get renamed, etc., and ideally people shouldn't have to follow a link to answer your question.

Comment: `mouseover` fires *repeatedly*, you may prefer `mouseenter` instead (especially as you're using `mouseleave` for the other half). (In fact, recent versions of jQuery have a shortcut for hooking up `mouseenter`/`mouseleave` pairs: [`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/).) But that's not the complete answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's my solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/azLMc/

I added a clearQueue() call to each mouseleave() function.  that will stop the mouseover animation, and perform the mouseleave animation immediately.  without it, the mouseover animation will continue to run, and if the mouse has left the area before it finishes, it won't register that it needs to run the mouseout animation.

After that, the first DIV was still getting stuck when the mouse left the document quickly.  so I added a mouseleave() to the .container DIV to return the first DIV to it's normal size, and sort of "reset".

Answer (score 2):

Either:

1.) Leave the height unchanged or

2.) have the hover trigger a separate offset DIV to show/hide

when the heights change anywhere below the top element, it's possible to on a move, to bring another element under the mouse, causing it to trigger it's expand/contract but it's delayed because of your transition times and in the time that cycling happens, another element moves either into or out of focus under your cursor.

Comment: +1 I think that's the bigger part of what's going on than the `mouseneter` thing. I tried an edit, even threw in `stop`s, helped some but not enough.